# when i have need to ionic 6 my my migration. then i have got the error like NullinjectorError in some module

Tags: dependency-injection, service, ionic6

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(EnquiryModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(EnquiryModule)[[object Object]:

NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!

at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11120)

at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287)

at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287)

at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287)

at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21814)

at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287)

at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21814)

at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287)

at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21814)

at Object.get (core.mjs:21491)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:1216)

at zone.js:1329

at _ZoneDelegate.push.3279._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443)

at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463)

at _ZoneDelegate.push.3279._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442)

at Zone.push.3279.Zone.runTask (zone.js:214)

at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632)

at ZoneTask.push.3279.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:529)

at invokeTask (zone.js:1714)